# Is it possible to move phpmyadmin to outside the root folder?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

currently phpmyadmin is located at www.website.com/phpmyadmin on an apache server but I'm wondering if it is possible to have it located outside the html folder and in a different directory but having it possible to access it myself to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can! Move it wherever you want. Then go to /etc/httpd/conf.d and create a new configuration file (maybe phpmyadmin.conf) and edit it. For instance, if you choose to move it to /usr/share/phpMyAdmin, the configuration file can be as follows:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin


<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    Options none
    AllowOverride Limit
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    Options none
    AllowOverride Limit
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>
```

Greetings

Comment: wow, thanks!  Is this of any use when protecting the database or an exercise in futility?

Comment: This is one of many things you can do in order to improve the security. For instance, [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-a-centos-7-server) is a useful link.

Comment: can't seem to get it working.  I've made the file and put it in the /etc/httpd/conf.d folder but all it has done is cause an error when I try going to the url www.website.com/phpmyadmin and the website appears to be still using the original phpmyadmin

Comment: Restart the apache server. I dont know which platform you have, try `service httpd restart`.

Comment: I did restart it but after that I got an "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Comment out every line in the brand new configuration file, and start debugging. First, comment out all the lines and restart apache. In that point you are as before, so apache should start correctly. Then delete the first, lets say, 2 comments, and then restart again the apache service. Keep doing this until find the configuration block with problems.

Comment: Also check the webserver error log and system log for information about that Internal Server Error.

Comment: it only seems to work if I only use the first two lines.  Would that be it?  I have renamed the original phpmyadmin folder and the site still appears to be working.  I'm not clear as to what the other items you included are for?

Comment: The other configuration blocks (`<Directory ...> ... </Directory>` blocks) are security configurations. For instance, the block 
`<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>`
restricts the access to the /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries directory. I don't know which version of phpMyAdmin you are using, verify that the directories exist.
But, I also think that checking the webserver error log and system log for information about that Internal Server Error is a good advice, as @IsaacBennetch said.